# Is it possible for me to use printf with PSTR?

Tags: c, avr, atmel

I'm trying to build a game with C that will print on puTTY and be controlled by a microcontroller. So basically to print things, I have a function called `move_cursor` to get to the place I want to print, and then I use PSTR to print it.

```
//to move
void move_cursor(int x, int y) {
    printf_P(PSTR("\x1b[%d;%dH"), y, x);
}

//to print things
printf_P(PSTR("Score: "));
```

It's fairly simple for me to just print things like 'Game Over' when I need to, but I realised it's a bit harder when I need to print something that constantly updates, like a score. I tried to use `printf` as I have a variable called `score` which I can sub in. But it seems like it doesn't work like that for PSTR. What exactly can I do if I'm trying to print something on the terminal with a part that updates frequently?

Comment: https://efundies.com/avr-and-printf/

Comment: I am not sure what you are actually asking? Just use `printf_P(PSTR("Score: %u"), currentScore);`?

Comment: @Rev1.0 yeah I figured I was overthinking it. Printf works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can replace the text on the left corner by using:

```
#define gotoxy(x, y) printf("\033[%d;%dH", x, y)
```

above the main function. Than use:

```
gotoxy(0, 0);
printf("%d",/*Some number*/);
```

to get to the left corner and print your score.

Comment: It may be better to use a subroutine instead of that macro. Because now the complete `printf` code will appear everywhere you use this macro and this wastes space. This might be a problem in larger programs where program memory turns out to be a precious resource! Also I think PSTR() is still needed because you want those strings to reside in program memory.